# how do I convert a date to YYYYMMDD?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have two tables with two different date formats and I need to compare them. I am trying to convert the field Q_RATE_DATE; how do I change it from `'27-JUN-12'` to `20120627`?

I tried:

```
TO_DATE(Q_RATE_DATE, 'DD-MON-YY', 'YYYYMMDD')
```

no luck, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Dates don't have intrinsic formats. At least one of your tables is holding dates as strings instead of as actual dates, which is bad practice. "no luck" isn't helpful though; the call you're making is invalid anyway, but you need to show which table has an actual date (or rather the datatypes of both columns), and whether either of the 'date' columns are indexed, and the volumes involved. You *probably* want to compare them as dates but that isn't necessarily the most efficient approach - it depends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it seems to me that BOTH columns are of character data type - otherwise it does not make sense to speak of "format." And in that case the correct solution is

```
to_char(to_date(Q_RATE_DATE, 'dd-mon-yy'), 'yyyymmdd')
```

(Well - actually the correct solution is to store dates in DATE data type, but it is entirely possible the OP has no control over that.)

Answer (score 6):

To render as text:

```
TO_CHAR(DATE_FIELD, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

To reconvert that text back to date:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATE_FIELD, 'YYYYMMDD'),'YYYYMMDD')
```

Editing based on Alex Poole's excellent comment. If you find that one date is stored as a string while the other is a date, you may need to use a mix of the above two queries.

To convert the text string into date:

```
TO_DATE(STR_DATE_FIELD, 'YYYYMMDD')
```